# NodeJS: "merge" two EventEmitter, like: eventemitter2 & HTTP Server

Tags: bind, apply, extend

I am new Here, and i have a litle question:
How i can "merge" or "extend" a EventEmitter with another ?

I use EventEmitter2 With namespace, and now i will attach an existence EvenEmitter to a namespace.

Example: dispatcher.attach("namespace", ee);

My function for this look like this:

```js
Dispatcher.prototype.attach = function(namespace, emitter) {

    var that = this;
    if (namespace && (typeof(emitter) === "object" && emitter._events)) {

      //console.log("Attach EventEmitter, Namespace: '%s'", namespace);
      Object.keys(emitter._events).forEach(function(event) {

        var eventname = namespace + that.delimiter + event;
        var listener = emitter._events[event];

        // add single function
        if (typeof(listener) === "function") {

          var func = listener.bind(emitter);
          that.on(eventname, func);

        }


        // add multiple functions
        if (typeof(listener) === "object") {
          for (var i = 0; i < listener.length; i++) {

            var func = listener[i].bind(emitter);
            that.on(eventname, func);

          }
        }

  emitter.on(event, function(){

    console.log(eventname, "=", event);

    var parameter = [];
    parameter.push(eventname);
    parameter.push(arguments);

    that.emit.apply(this, parameter);


  });




      });


      console.log(that.listenerTree);

    } else {
      throw new Error("Wrong parameter: dispatcher.attach('namespace', emitter)");
    }
```

Let me explain:

The problem is when the emitter (as example HTTP Server), emit a request, conneciton or what ever, the event from EvenEmiter2 is not fired. I am new on JavaScript / NodeJS

The goal is to listen & emit events from other EventEmitter over namespace like this:

```
dispatcher.on("http.request", function(req, res){
  res.end("test");
});
```

same on emit:

```
dispatcher.emit("idontknow.event", "Param1", "ParamN...");
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution:
Result: Works, but i not happy with that.
Can i avoid the statement check from "that.ignore" ?

```js
Dispatcher.prototype.attach = function(namespace, emitter) {

  var that = this;
  this.ignore = false;

  console.log("Attach; Namespace: %s", namespace);
  if (namespace && typeof(namespace) === "string" && (typeof(emitter) === "object" && emitter._events)) {
    Object.keys(emitter._events).forEach(function(event) {

      // namespace + event
      var eventname = namespace + that.delimiter + event;

      // Listen for Dispatcher events, then emit "sub" event
      // dispatcher.on("namespace.<event>") -> emitter.emit("<event>");
      that.on(eventname, function() {

        if (that.ignore === false || that.ignoreOff === true) {
          that.ignore = true;
          var parameter = [];
          parameter = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          parameter.unshift(event);
          emitter.emit.apply(emitter, parameter);
          that.ignore = false;
        }

      });

      // Listen for "sub" Emitter events, then emit dispatcher
      // emitter.on("<event>") -> dispatcher.emit("namespace.<event>")
      emitter.on(event, function() {

        if (that.ignore === false || that.ignoreOff === true) {
          that.ignore = true;
          var parameter = [];
          parameter = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          parameter.unshift(eventname);
          that.emit.apply(that, parameter);
          that.ignore = false;
        }

      });

    });
  } else {

    // wrong parameter...
    throw new Error("Wrong parameter: dispatcher.attach('namespace', ee)");

  }

};
```